# SVG Animation: Animate an arc as it is drawn

Tags: javascript, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I am drawing an Arc with SVG using the following snippet:

https://jsfiddle.net/e6dx9oza/293/

The starting and ending angle of the arc will be dynamically fed in when `describeArc` method is called to calculate the path.

Does anyone know how can I animate the arc as it gets drawn? Basically I want the arc to be drawn smoothly with a delay, instead of it getting drawn at one go as in the present case.

Comment: That's not an [arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_(geometry)), it's a [sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector). Can you please clarify your question to describe what you actually want? How is this thing supposed to be animated? Do you want one end fixed, for example?

Answer (score 5):

You question doesn't describe what you mean by "animate". Please think about that next time you ask a question.

I am going to assume you want the sector to open like a fan.

Here's one way to do it.

```js
function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
  var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees-90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

  return {
    x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
    y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
  };
}

function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle){

    var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
    var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);

    var arcSweep = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";

    var d = [
        "M", start.x, start.y, 
        "A", radius, radius, 0, arcSweep, 0, end.x, end.y,
        "L", x,y,
        "L", start.x, start.y
    ].join(" ");
    
    //console.log(d);

    return d;       
}


function animateSector(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, animationDuration) {

   var startTime = performance.now();

   function doAnimationStep() {
     // Get progress of animation (0 -> 1)
     var progress = Math.min((performance.now() - startTime) / animationDuration, 1.0);
     // Calculate the end angle for this point in the animation
     var angle = startAngle + progress * (endAngle - startAngle);
     // Calculate the sector shape
     var arc = describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, angle);
     // Update the path
     document.getElementById("arc1").setAttribute("d", arc);
     // If animation is not finished, then ask browser for another animation frame.
     if (progress < 1.0)
       requestAnimationFrame(doAnimationStep);
   }

   requestAnimationFrame(doAnimationStep);
}

animateSector(100, 100, 100, 120, 418.25, 1000);
```

```css
svg {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <path id="arc1" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/e6dx9oza/351/